# JavaFX display an object with multiple rows in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to display something similar to Twitter where you can see the user, it's profile picture and other things like the name and the body of the message itself, but I can't seem to think a similar approach.
[This  is what I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMmOK.jpg)

What I want to do is load all the messages and user profile and other details from a database with this format, but the only way I can think of doing this is by using a TableView with TableColumns on the side, but this approach is horrible and I couldn't seem to think of anything else.

[This is the only method I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqvMS.png)

Comment: Looks more like a `ListView` with a custom `ListCell` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableView's are great when your layout and data needs to be something like a spreadsheet with rows and columns.  What you have pictured isn't anything like this, so the best approach is to use a ListView.  A ListView isn't really just a one column table, it's more like a scrolling pane of windows.  You create the layout of the enclosed window, and the ListView takes care of loading the data into the each window.

The main thing to remember is that you don't rebuild the layout each time the data is loaded.  Create the layout once in the constructor of the ListCell, make the widgets that you need to put data into instance variables of your ListCell class, and then you can override `updateItem()` to get the data into them.

So for this, the ListCell is a VBox with two HBox's in it.  The one on the left has the avatar and user name, and the one on the right has the title and the message.  There's some simple styling, because it looked ugly without it.

```
public class MessagingListView extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<ListModel> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new MessageCell());
        Scene scene = new Scene(listView, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/default.css");
        primaryStage.show();
        ObservableList<ListModel> listModels = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        listView.setItems(listModels);
        loadData(listModels);
    }


    public class MessageCell extends ListCell<ListModel> {
        HBox graphic;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        Text nameText = new Text();
        Text titleText = new Text();
        Text messageText = new Text();

        public MessageCell() {
            nameText.getStyleClass().add("label-text");
            titleText.getStyleClass().add("heading-text");
            imageView.setFitWidth(80);
            imageView.setFitHeight(80);
            messageText.setWrappingWidth(260);
            HBox messageBox = new HBox(messageText);
            messageBox.getStyleClass().add("standard-border");
            messageBox.setPadding(new Insets(6));
            VBox leftBox = new VBox(5, imageView, nameText);
            VBox rightBox = new VBox(5, titleText, messageBox);
            leftBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            graphic = new HBox(10, leftBox, rightBox);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(ListModel item, boolean empty) {
            System.out.println("here ");
            if ((item != null) && !empty) {
                System.out.println("updating");
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                nameText.textProperty().bind(item.userNameProperty());
                titleText.textProperty().bind(item.titleProperty());
                messageText.textProperty().bind(item.messageProperty());
                imageView.imageProperty().bind(item.imageProperty());
                setGraphic(graphic);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadData(ObservableList<ListModel> listModels) {
        listModels.add(new ListModel("fred",
                                     new Image("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/145/145859.png"),
                                     "I'm Upset",
                                     "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, " + "totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae " + "vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut " + "odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni"));
        listModels.add(new ListModel("GeorgeX",
                                     new Image("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3048/3048163.png"),
                                     "This is the Title",
                                     "adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam "
                                             + "quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam"));
    }

    class ListModel {
        StringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        StringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty("");

        public ListModel(String userName, Image image, String title, String message) {
            this.userName.set(userName);
            this.image.set(image);
            this.title.set(title);
            this.message.set(message);
        }

        public StringProperty userNameProperty() {
            return userName;
        }

        public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
            return image;
        }

        public StringProperty titleProperty() {
            return title;
        }

        public StringProperty messageProperty() {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

The CSS elements look like this:

```
.root{
    -theme-colour : #017987;
    -theme-deep-colour : derive(-theme-colour, -15%);
    -theme-font-colour : derive(-theme-colour, -50%);
    -theme-deep-font-colour : derive(-theme-font-colour, -50%);
    -theme-light-colour : derive(-theme-colour, +90%);
    -contrast-colour : #f89642;
    -contrast-deep-colour : derive(-contrast-colour, -20%);
    -near-black : #252535;
    -theme-font-family : 'Calibri';
}

.label-text {
    -fx-font-family : -theme-font-family;
    -fx-font-size: 17;
    -fx-fill: -theme-colour;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.heading-text {
    -fx-font-family : -theme-font-family;
    -fx-font-size: 24;
    -fx-fill: -contrast-colour;
    -fx-stroke: -theme-font-colour;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.standard-border {
   -fx-border-color : -theme-colour, -theme-deep-colour;
   -fx-border-insets: 0, 0 -1.4 -1.4 0;
   -fx-border-radius : 4px, 6px;
   -fx-border-width : 1.5px, 0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I just couldn't think of a workaround, I am very grateful.